# Automatic logging into Data Explorer

Tags: support, data-explorer, login

On most Stack Exchange sites, when I visit them I am already logged in if I have logged in before.

Why isn't it the case with [Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Global login is not open source, nor really open-source-able.

Since the [Data Explorer *is*](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.DataExplorer), we can't easily enable global login for it.

Comment: Is this also the reason I have to log into data.se anew every day, while I this is not the case at all other SE sites? (This might also have something to do with my using [Ghostery](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/ghostery/), but that doesn't seem to be a problem for other sites.)

Answer (score 4):

Having to relogin every day is a right pain -- especially since unlogged-in users have to always fill in the CAPTCHA field to run queries.

Since the promised fixes may be a long time coming, I made **a userscript that fixes that.**

#### Update:

My version of the script also **redirects back to the desired target page after login.**
I just released [that version on GitHub](https://github.com/BrockA/SE-misc/blob/master/Stack%20Exchange%20Data%20Explorer%20(SEDE)%20auto%20login.user.js).

Here's an [install link](https://github.com/BrockA/SE-misc/raw/master/Stack%20Exchange%20Data%20Explorer%20(SEDE)%20auto%20login.user.js). (Requires the Tampermonkey or the Violentmonkey browser extension.)

**For more information, see [the script's new home page on Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/questions/8366/data-explorer-sede-auto-login-that-redirects-back-to-original-target-page).**

Comment: As a side note, the fact that you have to log in so frequently is a bug and will be fixed in the near future.

Comment: Thanks, @TimStone.  Looking forward to the fix.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the script! Have you considered putting it on StackApps?